# OpenLayers.Format.GML.parseFeature() with GML v3 data

Tags: openlayers-2, gml

I have a partial *GML* object with the geometry type `polygon`. The GML version must be 3+ since the coordinates are wrapped in the `gml:posList` tag:

```
<gml:Polygon srsName="EPSG:25832" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">  
     <gml:exterior>  
         <gml:LinearRing srsName="EPSG:25832">  
             <gml:posList>
                 N points where N is an even integer.
             </gml:posList>  
         </gml:LinearRing>  
     </gml:exterior> 
</gml:Polygon>
```

I am using OpenLayers 2.10 and I am trying to convert the GML object into an OpenLayers feature using the *OpenLayers.Format.GML* class.

When executing the `parseFeature` method, which later calls the `parseGeometry.linestring` I encounter this comment:

```
/**
* Two coordinate variations to consider:
* 1) <gml:posList dimension="d">x0 y0 z0 x1 y1 z1</gml:posList>
* 2) <gml:coordinates>x0, y0, z0 x1, y1, z1</gml:coordinates>
*/
```

And this line of code which assumes the `dimension` attribute to be present:

```
var dim = parseInt(nodeList[0].getAttribute("dimension"));
```

In *OpenLayers.Format.GML.v3* the same line of code looks like this:

```
var dim = parseInt(node.getAttribute("dimension")) || 2;
```

The problematic difference for me is the `|| 2` part which assumes that a missing dimension means 2 dimensional - which is what I want.
Then why not use the *v3* edition, but the *OpenLayers.Format.GML.v3* does not implement the `parseFeature` method.

I am recieving *GML* features from various services and I do not control them.

**What is the best approach to handle this problem?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick glance it looks like the v2 and v3 JS files derive from base (definitely makes sense too) which offers a read method. Try checking that out.

See: http://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/2.x/lib/OpenLayers/Format/GML/Base.js#L151

If that is not complete or does not meet your needs you can just modify the source. Given the generous licensing and the nature of JavaScript you could just add it in yourself or better yet create a pull request for that change.

See: http://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/2.x/lib/OpenLayers/Format/GML.js#L348

If you feel the need to hack something messy together you can also add that attribute to the nodes:

```
setMissingDefaults = function(node){ /* magic stuff */ }
OpenLayers.Format.GML.parseFeature(setMissingDefaults(node));
```

Comment: I cannot use the `read` method, since I don't have the rest of the GML document - it needs the `featureMember(s)` tag. I could fix it my self, but I am more curious to whether there is a reason for not including the default dimension in the *GML.js* file. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: The standards documents don't make much sense with respect to posList. Old v3 docs define a dimension property as "...the number of entries in the list" while the new version has a count property instead which "specifies the number of direct positions in the list". After reading this all the examples of this tag however have a dimension="2" or 3. My best guess is that srsDimension is supposed to be used on the posList or up the hierarchy instead of dimension on the posList but nobody cared enough to change. Hope somebody else can chime in with some better info and background on it.